# Is it possible to perform hyper parameter tuning using gridsearchCV with make_pipeline from sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

Currently, I can build a model through the use of `make_column_transformer` and `make_pipeline` that looks something like:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

[in]: dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()

[in]: column_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), ['var1', 'var2',
                                              'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6'
                                              ]),
    remainder='passthrough')

[in]: column_trans.fit_transform(X)

[in] pipe = make_pipeline(column_trans, dtc)

[in]: cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='accuracy').mean()

[out]: ... prediction
```

I've gone through the documentation and can't seem to find anything that speaks to streamlining the process into gridsearchCV

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on scikit-learn where GridSearchCV is used in a pipeline: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html

Your mentioned `make_pipeline`method is a "shorthand for the Pipeline constructor" ([Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html)), which just returns the pipeline object. So at the end, using the pipeline constructor directly will lead to the same result and you can orientate yourself with their example.

I am assuming, you want to execute the `GridSearchCV` before your `cross_val_score()` method call, to identify the best parameters.

So for that, you could adjust your code similary to theirs:

```
search = GridSearchCV(pipe, your_param_grid)
search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(search.best_params_)
```